# Flare the scent?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Dialogue from game about vampire.

> Remember, I have a good nose for machinations. I can flare the scent at a
>   mile.

What does it mean - flare the scent? Maybe misspell?

Answer (score 1):

If your nose "flares," it means your nose puffs out from taking a large breath of air. In actuality, it's the twitching of certain muscles of the face that would cause nostrils to look flared. I've never heard "flare the scent" before, but I assume it means the vampire can breathe in very deeply to smell something from a mile away.